# Evaluating an integral numerically using Matlab

Tags: matlab, numerical-integration

```
fun= @(x)exp(- a*(d+1).*(t-x)./(d-(t-x))  ) *b.*exp(-b*x); 
int= integral(fun,0,t);
```

Since I did not find a closed form solution, I am using the above code in Matlab to numericaly evaluate the integral.

I am evaluating this integral for different values of `d`.
The problem is that when I take `d<t` I get `inf`. Any idea what is the problem ? and what approach can be used to evaluate the integral in this case ?

Note that `a`, `b`, `d`, and `t` are all positive. Ex: `a=0.1`, `b=1`, `t=4`.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the denominator of the first term of `fun` you see that it depends on `t`, `x` and `d`.  So what happens if `d == t` and `x == 0`?  The denominator goes to `0.0`.  If `d > t` there is no positive value for `x` that will cause the denominator to go to `0.0`.

If we let `d == t` and plot that first term for values of `x = 3:.001:5` we see this:

[image]

That discontinuity causes the values to be in the range `[-Inf, Inf]`.  Now if we plot `exp` of these values we see this:

[image]

Comment: But when I take `d=t`, I don't get `Inf`.

Comment: Could you please tell me what approach can be used to evaluate the integral if `d< t` ?